# What does "enfeoffment of a right to tax people" mean in this context?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> It has to be remembered that the kingdom of Sweden had no real system
> of enfeoffment. **It was not the peasants themselves as vassals who were
> enfeoffed, but the right to tax them**. In central and eastern Europe a
> high proportion of the peasant class was tied to the land, which was
> owned by autocratic feudal masters. The king gave them their fiefs in
> exchange for their loyalty and support in war.
>
> (bolds by me)
>
> - A history of Finland

I know that enfeoffment (enfieffment) means that a lord gives a peasant some amount of land. And the peasant in return promises the lord that he (the peasant) will serve (military or politically) the lord.

You can see that author used the term "enfeoffment of a peasant". I understand enfeoffment of a peasant as giving him land and making him vassal. But in the second part of the sentence "it was the right to tax them (peasants) which was enfeoffed". What does enfeoffment of a right mean?

Comment: [TILANW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feoffment). Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Today I learned a new word!

Comment: Good luck to you then)

Comment: It seems from your post that *enfeoffment* is the giving of a good, the right to a piece of land, to someone. In this case, the good that is given is the right to tax someone.

Comment: Problem is in that "who were". This is passive voice. So "the peasants themselves as vassals who were enfeoffed" means (i assume) "peasants were not given land and weren't made vassals to lords".
And this does not make any sense for the second part of the sentence.

Comment: If it said: "it was not the land .. but the right to tax peasants" it would make sence. Am I right?

Comment: @1amroff Maybe the sense is that when the land fief is conferred, the vassals on that land came along with land. Then it would make sense to say that the vassals were not part of the fief, just the right to tax them. But I'm really not sure.